# Get org-mode link label from internal link?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** how do I extract an `org-mode` link label?

Given an `org-mode` [internal link](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html) with the following format:

```
[[link-target][link-label]]
```

*How do I extract `link-label`?*

I need to process the link *as a string*, not interactively in an `org-mode` buffer.  I could write a regexp to do this, but am wondering if there's a function already built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this. The regexp you want is already defined in the variable org-bracket-link-regexp.

```
(let ((s "[[link-target][link-label]]"))
  (string-match org-bracket-link-regexp s)
  (list
   (match-string 1 s)
   (match-string 3 s)))
```

This should return a list of ("link-target" "link-label")

Answer (score 0):

[`org-copy-visible`](http://orgmode.org/org.html#index-org_002dcopy_002dvisible-76), bound to <kbd>C-c C-x v</kbd>, should do the job for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work for my use case, which is to process a string.  I've updated the question.